# Get element values from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

This is my XML data from file

```
<item id="ncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml" />
<item id="W000Title" href="000Title.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="W01MB154" href="01MB154.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="WTOC" href="TOC.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
```

---

I want to get element values using C# in Store application.
I'm getting the values, but it's not the right way & I'm unable to go to the next step.

```
    string fileContents3 = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    xmlDoc1.LoadXml(fileContents3);
    XmlNodeList item = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("item");
    for (uint k = 0; k < item.Length; k++)
    {
        XmlElement ele1 = (XmlElement)item.Item(k);
        var attri1 = ele1.Attributes;
        var attrilist1 = attri1.ToArray();
        for (int l = 0; l < attrilist1.Length; l++)
        {
            if (attrilist1[l].NodeName == "id")
            {

                    ids2 = attrilist1[0].NodeValue.ToString();
                    ids3 = attrilist1[1].NodeValue.ToString();
            }
        } 
   }
```

---

Rather than this way I want to know any way to get element values of attribute "id"

Comment: you have to load the contents of the file directly into the XMLDocument that has a path parameter.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do, but you can using XPath if you want to find particular ID's Item Node. otherwise your code is pretty much good, and instead of For(int i=... ) I use foreach , and then XMLNode node; I simply use node.Attributes["id"] where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function if you want to get the value of an attribute on a `XmlNode` object:

```
    public static string GetAttributeValue(XmlNode node, string attributeName)
    {
        XmlAttribute attr = node.Attributes[attributeName];
        return (attr == null) ? null : attr.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
**The type or namespace name 'XmlNode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Perhaps you miss the `using System.Xml` at the beginning of your cs file

Comment: Thanks. It not yet worked for me.
 I want it for Windows store app. These properties are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you require to use XPath, you can use as follows,

```
      XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(@"c:\users\saravanan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test\test\XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlNodeList itemNodes = document.SelectNodes("//item");

        foreach (XmlElement node in itemNodes)
        {
            if (node.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (node.HasAttribute("id"))
                {
                    Console.Write(node.Attributes["id"]);
                }

            }
        }

        var itemNodeswithAttribute = document.SelectNodes("//item[href=toc.ncx]");

        itemNodeswithAttribute = document.SelectNodes("//item[@href='toc.ncx']");
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want it for Windows store app. These properties are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileContents3 = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
xmlDoc1.LoadXml(fileContents3);
XmlNodeList item = xmlDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("item");
        for (uint k = 0; k < item.Length; k++)
        {
            XmlElement ele1 = (XmlElement)item.Item(k);
            string foo = ele1.Attributes[0].NodeValue.ToString();
        }
```

I simplified your code a little. Hope this will help you.
I assume that the id Attribute is always on first Position (Index 0).

Comment: It works for me. But after this I want to compare these values to another tag values which are same file. 
 `<itemref idref="W000Title" />
  <itemref idref="W01MB154" />` How can I compare the `id` values in `item` element & `idref` values in `itemref` tag